# Count non-null variables and put into a new columb by grouping

Tags: r, null, missing-data

Here is head of my dataset as follows:

```
ID    L.NO   Root1  Root2  Root3
1     2120   SX     NA     NA
2     2121   NC     NA     NA
3     2122   NA     NA     SX
4     2223   NA     CX     PX
5     2224   NA     SX     LX
```

I'd like to count non-null variables and put into a new column by grouping ID. How can I do that in R?

```
ID    L.NO   Root1  Root2  Root3 NewCol
1     2120   SX     NA     NA    2
2     2121   NC     NA     NA    2
3     2122   NA     NA     SX    2
4     2223   NA     CX     PX    1
5     2224   NA     SX     LX    1
```

Comment: Why is the 2nd row, `NewCol` is `2` ? Are we grouping by `ID` column? In this example all IDs are unique, please provide a better example.

Comment: Try `rowSums(!is.na(df))`

Comment: Because there is 2 NA which belongs to ID 1.

Comment: rowSums(!is.na(df)) works but how can I put the results to a new column grouping by ID?

Comment: `ds$NewCol <- rowSums(is.na(df)) `

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I missed the point :)